# Форма не сохраняется django formset

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
def expert_edit(request, pk):
    """Редактирования  данных экспертизы"""
 
    expert = get_object_or_404(Expert, pk=pk)
    formset = FileExpertFormset(queryset=ExpertFiles.objects.none())
    if request.method == "POST":
        expert_form = ExpertNewForm(request.POST,  instance=expert)
        formset = FileExpertFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if expert_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            expert = expert_form.save()
            for form in formset:
                print(form.as_table())
                print(form.instance)
                inst = form.save(commit=False)
                if inst.scan_doc:
                    inst.files = expert
                    inst.save
            return redirect('/expert/')
    else:
        error = ' Форма не верно заполнена'
        expert_form = ExpertNewForm(instance=expert)
        list_files = expert.files_expert.all()
        template_name = 'dist/expert/edit.html'
        data = {'expert_edit': expert_form,
                'list_files': list_files,
                'pk': pk,
                'formset': formset,
                'error': error
                 }
        return render(request, template_name, data)
```

models.py

```
class ExpertFiles(models.Model):
    """Таблица прикрепленных файлов Экспертизы """
 
    TYPES = (
        (1, 'Акт Осмотра'),
        (2, 'Экспертиза'),
        (3, 'Калькуляция'),
        (3, 'Скан чека'),
    )
    types = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
                                            choices=TYPES,
                                            null=True,
                                            default=None,
                                            blank=True,
                                        )
 
    files = models.ForeignKey(
                                Expert,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='files_expert',
                                blank=True,
                                null=True,
                                verbose_name='Прикрепленные файлы (Expert)'
                            )
 
    description = models.CharField(
                                    max_length=100,
                                    verbose_name='Описание '
                                )
    scan_doc = models.FileField(
                                upload_to='media/doc_expert/',
                                null=True,
                                default=None,
                                verbose_name="Файл"
                            )
    author = models.OneToOneField(
                                    User,
                                    db_column='user',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True,
                                )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
 
 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Файл Экспертизы'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Файлы Экспертизы'
```

forms.py

```
FileExpertFormset = modelformset_factory(
    ExpertFiles,
    fields=('files',
            'types',
            'description',
            'scan_doc'
            ),
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'files': TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Файлы Expert'
            }
        ),
        'types': Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Тип файла'
            }
        ),
        'description': TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Описание к файлу'
            }
        ),
        'scan_doc': FileInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Файл',
        }
        ),
    }
)
```

edit.html

```html
<form method="POST" action="" class="form-control"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <label class="form-label" for="formrow-firstname-input">Выбор Заказчика</label>
                {{ expert_edit.client }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <label class="form-label" for="formrow-firstname-input">ТС Заказчика</label>
                {{ expert_edit.car }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mt-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label>Контрагент:</label>
                        {{ expert_edit.contragent }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Стоимость</label>
                        {{ expert_edit.summa_exp }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" id="datepicker2" for="formrow-firstname-input">Дата завершение
                            ЭО</label>
                        {{ expert_edit.data_out }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-md-15">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label class="form-label" for="formrow-firstname-input">Вид оценки</label>
                            {{ expert_edit.type }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-nowrap table-hover mb-0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">№</th>
                        <th scope="col">Тип расчета</th>
                        <th scope="col">Сумма</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">01</th>
                        <td><a href="#" class="text-dark">Востановительный ремонт без износа</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ expert_edit.price_nwear }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">02</th>
                        <td><a href="#" class="text-dark">Востановительный ремонт с износом</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ expert_edit.price_wwear }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">03</th>
                        <td><a href="#" class="text-dark">Средняя цена по рынку</a></td>
                        <td>
                            {{ expert_edit.price_mmarket }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">04</th>
                        <td><a href="#" class="text-dark">Годные остатки</a></td>
                        <td>
                            {{ expert_edit.price_uleftovers }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">05</th>
                        <td><a href="#" class="text-dark">Сумма утраченной товарной
                            стоимости</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ expert_edit.price_uts }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">06</th>
                        <td><a href="#" class="text-dark">Сумма ущерба</a></td>
                        <td>
                            {{ expert_edit.price_nwear }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="row mb-4">
                    <label class="form-label" for="formrow-firstname-input">Комментарий к экспертному
                        заключению</label>
                    {{ expert_edit.comment }}
                </div>
                <hr>
                <h3>Документы Экспертизы</h3>
                <div data-repeater-item class="row">
                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                    {% for form in formset %}
                    <div class="row form-row">
                        <div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                            {{ form.types }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-lg-5">
                            {{ form.description }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                            {{ form.scan_doc }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="minus" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-success remove-form-row">-
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="plus" type="button"
                                class="btn btn-success add-form-row">Добавить
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="col-15">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary w-md" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Совсем неплохо будет, если вы будете проверять свои значения и как-то на это реагировать.

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass



# .......
    if request.method == "POST":
        expert_form = ExpertNewForm(request.POST,  instance=expert)
        formset = FileExpertFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if expert_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            expert = expert_form.save()
            for form in formset:
                print(form.as_table())
                print(form.instance)
                inst = form.save(commit=False)
                if inst.scan_doc:
                    inst.files = expert
                    inst.save
                else:
                    raise MyException('is not inst.scan_doc')    
            return redirect('/expert/')
       else:
            raise MyException(f'expert_form or formset is not valid: {expert_form.errors};{formset.errors}')
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет очень дельный, что условия должны  иметь ветку истину и ложь, но я не пойму где моя ошибка в сохранении(

Comment: ошибок не возникает? если нет, то еще глаз зацепился за  "inst.save". мне кажется или правильно " inst.save()"

Comment: Спасибо, большое, вы правы оказались банальная не внимательность при copypaste